# Need for jquery plugin for ajax upload with progress bar for ASP .NET MVC 3 project

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, ajax-upload

I search in google, but I don't find anything for me.

So I want plug-in for uploading files via ajax and there are some problems

1.It must have progress bar to show upload progress!
2.I want to send info from textboxes to controller(for renaming file)
3.My action should start work only when uploading process is complete...

What plug-ins can you suggest?
Also, it will be more helpful, if you write here example for ASP .NET MVC 3 too...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

[I use jQuery File Upload for all that stuff in MVC3](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload). The only caveat is that because it's a pure HTML/JS solution you don't have progress bars in IE (because IE doesn't provide any way to handle it).

For an IE-compatible solution for an upload progress bar you have no choice but to use Flash right now.

Answer (score 0):

[plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) works well and has a lot of compatibility built in.